# Remove Archived option from status field

Tags: joomla-3.x, form-fields-types

I use the below form field in the filter_mypage.xml of my custom component.

```
<field
    name="state"
    type="status"
    label="JOPTION_SELECT_PUBLISHED"
    onchange="this.form.submit();">
      <option value="">JOPTION_SELECT_PUBLISHED</option>
</field>
```

By default this shows the options `Trashed`, `Unpublished`, `Published`, `Archived`, `All`

I do not want the `Archived` option and want to remove from the list.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

You can either make your own options (see [Hasanalsamra's answer)](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/15225/154) or use the `filter` option of the status field:

```
<field
    name="state"
    type="status"
    filter="*,0,1,-2"
    label="JOPTION_SELECT_PUBLISHED"
    onchange="this.form.submit();"
    >
    <option value="">JOPTION_SELECT_PUBLISHED</option>
</field>
```

### For reference:

* = all
0 = unpublished
1 = published
2 = archived
-2 = trashed

An example of this usage can be found in the core backend component com_menu (\administrator\components\com_menus\models\forms\filter_items.xml)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can make your own options, here is how:

```
<field
    name="state"
    type="list"
    label="JOPTION_SELECT_PUBLISHED"
    onchange="this.form.submit();">
    <option value="">JOPTION_SELECT_PUBLISHED</option>
    <option value="-2">JTRASHED</option>
    <option value="0">JUNPUBLISHED</option>
    <option value="1">JPUBLISHED</option>
    <option value="*">JALL</option>
</field>
```